# Rshiny - Conditional Panel on Dynamic ID

Tags: shiny

I am new to Rshiny and this is my first question.

I am trying to insert a checkbox and a conditional panel for every dataset in a folder. How do I make the Conditional Panel only visible when the Checkbox is selected?

As the id is dynamic, I cant access it value. Please help me, TIA

```
   dataDetails <- function(id,nameDef) {
    shiny::tags$div(
    class="dataSource",
   fillRow(
  checkboxInput(inputId = paste0("dataSource-", id), 
                label = nameDef,
                width = "100%"),

  conditionalPanel(paste0("input.dataSource-",id), 
                   # uiOutput("dataSourcesDate")) 
                   actionButton("dfcvs","dfvs")
  )
),
br(),
hr()
  )
 }



    lapply(list.files(path = "savefiles"), function(x) {
      insertUI(
   selector = '#dataSources',
    ui = tagList(dataDetails(
     id = x,
     nameDef = x
    ))
  )
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usually best practice to include a minimal working example of your code so people can see what you are trying to do. checkboxInput takes a value of 0 when not selected and 1 when selected. The below code shows a simple working example of how you can get conditionalPanel working along with your checkboxInputs:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    checkboxInput("checkbox1", "Check Box 1", value = FALSE),
    checkboxInput("checkbox2", "Check Box 2", value = FALSE),
    checkboxInput("checkbox3", "Check Box 3", value = FALSE),
    checkboxInput("checkbox4", "Check Box 4", value = FALSE),
    conditionalPanel("input.checkbox1 == 1", "Check Box 1 Ticked"),
    conditionalPanel("input.checkbox2 == 1", "Check Box 2 Ticked"),
    conditionalPanel("input.checkbox3 == 1", "Check Box 3 Ticked"),
    conditionalPanel("input.checkbox4 == 1", "Check Box 4 Ticked")
    )
  )

server <- shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {

  }
) 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```